# Add LEDs to ceiling fan

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, led

My baby seems to love watching the ceiling fan spin. Not sure if he is retarded, bored or just super fascinated. Anyway; I was thing, perhaps I could add a few LEDs to the fan blades.

My question to the group:

Could I replace my blades with acrylic blades, then wire up LEDs at the start of each blade? My fan doesn't have a light on it.

Or...I don't know, add some kind of self powering LED, that's powered by the motion? I imagine I could drill a hole for the LEDs, place a coin holder battery pack on each place and that would last some time.

Any ideas on the best method?

Comment: "Not sure if he is retarded, bored or just super fascinated." He's a baby.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you would be better off just getting a lighted mobile. Leave the fan alone. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Could you rig lights on the fan? Sure, though powering and balancing them is a challenge.

Should you? Probably not for this purpose. At the slowest speed, fan blades are moving fast enough that you'd probably just see rings of light, except when your eyes are moving or you blink to "strobe" it. Some amusing things could be done with that --  websearch "Persistance of vision bicycle display", which would also point you to off-the-shelf solutions you might be able to install in the fan -- but more amusing for you than for the kid.

Other comments withheld as a public service